# add a new robot to ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how can i add a new rebot to Ros,i want to control my robot from ros, how i can do to integrate my robot in ros.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271155/add-a-new-robot-to-ros/) by [nachatad](https://answers.ros.org/users/31955/nachatad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Essentially you'll want to make an URDF file for your robot (URDF stands for Unified Robot Description Format). You can learn how to do that using these [URDF tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials).

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2017-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nachatad](https://answers.ros.org/users/31955/nachatad/) on 2017-09-19**:
Thank you for your answer

it's for visual robots, I think this is not my case, I need to integrate a real robot like Adept Cobra this is just an example. it already has a program to use it but I would like to integrate it with ros.
thank you

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-19**:
@nachatad URDF files are for more than just visualization. You can use them to publish the tf of your robot (which is useful for many things) via `robot_state_publisher`. You'll probably want to take a look at the link that @Airuno2L posted

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2017-09-19**:
You also define motors, transmissions, controllers, sensors, etc in the URDF. It is how your robot will interact with ROS.

**Comment by [nachatad](https://answers.ros.org/users/31955/nachatad/) on 2017-09-20**:
Thank you for your support